# How do I open Intent from drawer's selected fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, navigation-drawer

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.example.mystifying;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;


import com.example.mystifying.fragments.HowToPlay;
import com.example.mystifying.fragments.PrivacyPolicy;
import com.example.mystifying.fragments.RateThisApp;
import com.example.mystifying.fragments.Share;
import com.example.mystifying.fragments.home;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    NavigationView navigationView;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    Fragment fragment = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();


        if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame) == null) {
            loadFragment(new home());
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.home:
                        fragment = new home();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        break;
                    case R.id.howToPlay:
                        fragment = new HowToPlay();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        break;
                    case R.id.rate:
                        fragment = new RateThisApp();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        break;
                    case R.id.privacy:
                        fragment = new PrivacyPolicy();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        break;
                    case R.id.share:
                        fragment = new Share();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        break;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment).commit();
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#E91E63"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
          />

    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
        />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**JoinOrStart.java**

```
package com.example.mystifying;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.mystifying.databinding.ActivityJoinOrStartBinding;
import com.example.mystifying.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class JoinOrStart extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActivityJoinOrStartBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityJoinOrStartBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        binding.btnJoin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent joinIntent = new Intent( JoinOrStart.this, Join.class);
                startActivity(joinIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_join_or_start.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FBE9E7"
    tools:context=".JoinOrStart">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bgWall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="495dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:alpha="0.3"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_wall" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/starDivider"
            style="@style/Divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/bgWall" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/threeFriends"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_friends_three"

            />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnStart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/starDivider"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

            android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_start"


            android:backgroundTint="@null"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="@string/start"

            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnJoin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btnStart"


            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"


            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_join"
            android:backgroundTint="@null"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"

            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="@string/join"
            android:textColor="#E91E63"
            android:textSize="24sp"

            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Join.java**

```
package com.example.mystifying;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class Join extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_join);
    }
}
```

**activity_join.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFCDD2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".Join">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFEBEE"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:text="@string/join"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="50sp" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <View style="@style/Divider" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:text="@string/code"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"

                android:textColor="#E57373"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <View style="@style/Divider" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:text="@string/ask_to_the_person_who_started_game"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#C2185B"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <com.chaos.view.PinView
            style="@style/PinWidget.PinView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:itemBackground="#FFF3E0"
            app:cursorColor="@color/black"
            app:hideLineWhenFilled="true"
            app:itemCount="6"
            app:itemHeight="45dp"
            app:itemRadius="5dp"
            app:itemWidth="45dp"
            app:lineColor="#F06292" />


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnStart"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"

            android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
            android:backgroundTint="@null"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"

            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="@string/verify_code"

            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

> If I change the intent filter from manifest then it is working fine - I can
> tap on Join and Join Intent opens. But from navigation drawer home fragment/default fragment nothing is happening not even the app is crashing or logcat is showing
> anything where the problem is ...

[image: I want to jump to Join Activity on tapping Join]

[image: Here I want to come from Drawer's home fragment and by tapping on join button]

Comment: Can you share home/default fragment?

Comment: `if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame) == null) {
            loadFragment(new home());
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
`
From MainActivity.java it is taking default
Refer first Image

Comment: activity_join_or_start.xml is the default activity

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Solved:**
I just copied my code from join_or_start.xml to home fragment xml and then in home java file I inflated and set onClickListener to it this solved my problem.